# Android Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This might sound highly noobish question but let me ask it any way.

I am new to Android and Java programming. I have been coding in C for a while. I have tried to analyze and understand Java Code for fragments in Android(that's my way of learning a programming language).

The scenario:

Say i have a main activity with 2 fragments.

1st fragment (fragment_bottom) has a load image button which loads an image from the gallery.

2nd fragment has the 2 textviews.The 2 fragments dont communicate with each other.

Now my question is Why do i write the button onClick code in MainActivity.java and not in fragment_bottom.java (the fragment name is fragment_bottom). The reason i have this doubt is the, button belongs to fragment_bottom so according to my knowledge you should write code for handling the button click in fragment_bottom.java.

I apologize for my noobness.But if anybody could help me out it would be great!

Comment: use interface for communication of two fragments..and communication is possible with the help of activity.

Comment: You can write the onClick code inside the fragment class.

Comment: Of course one can set onClick listener in fragment. Its totally depends upon how one design the activity to handle button.

Comment: Yes, u can write onClick inside Fragment or u can handle that click event in activity also, bcz Activity can have multiple fragments. But my suggestion is to write onClick inside fragment..as click event is associated to fragment_bottom.java

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick response.It's really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely (and you probably should) set/write your onClick listener inside your fragment. 
If you're confused here's an example where we have a `Button` named mButton and I set mButton's `OnClickListener`:

```
public class BottomFragment extends Fragment {
    private Button mButton;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom, container, false);
        mButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Whatever you write inside here will get
                        // executed when you click on mButton
                    }
                }
        );
        return view;
    }
}
```